# How do I create a file inside a hidden directory?

Tags: c, file-io, file-copying

Really, I'm just generally confused on how to create a file in a subdirectory of the current working directory, but especially if it's hidden.

Say `char* backup` contains the name of the file we're creating with an `open()` call.

Say there's a hidden folder which already exists called `.mybackup`.

How do I create the file inside of `.mybackup`? Hopefully without chdir'ing twice.

Where I'm at so far:

```
int filewrite;
filewrite = open(backup, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
```

Comment: `open` is not a C library call but comes from your OS. Please tag your question appropriately with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend the filename with the directory you'd like it to be placed in.  Or, `chdir`ing twice would also be acceptable.

```
char* backup = "backup.sql";   // Assuming this comes from somewhere else (not constant)

const char* targetDir = ".mybackup/";   // (No leading slash)

// Allocate a buffer for the filename (remembering +1 for null-terminator!)
char* path = (char*)malloc(strlen(targetDir) + strlen(backup) + 1);

strcpy(path, targetDir);   // Copy in the target directory part
strcat(path, backup);      // Copy in the filename part


filewrite = open(path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);  // Open the file

free(path);   // Free the buffer
```

Comment: So, (in Unix/Linux!) backup would need to contain `/.mybackup/x.txt`?

Comment: @Aerovistae Leave off the leading slash. Without it, it becomes a *relative* path (relative to your current directory).

Answer (score 1):

```
int filewrite;
filewrite = open(backup, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644)
```

where backup contains "folder\filename" where folder is relative from the folder *you are in*

Comment: So, (in Unix/Linux!) backup would need to contain `/.mybackup/x.txt`?